# Funnel theory exists?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a funnel and I notice when I try to pour powdered sugar through it, it blocks up unless I tap it. If I put sand in the funnel, it goes through.

Is there a theory of funnels that can predict what materials will pass through a funnel of given dimensions?

Comment: Granular flow is a area of active research that features several hard problems and a disgusting number of ways to undergo sudden phase transitions. It's also *way* outside my ken. I've seen a few colloquium talks, that's all.

Comment: Here is a really nice simple derivation of a formula for granular flow through a funnel: http://www.scienceandsums.com/2014/02/26/investigating-flow-rate-of-granularpowdered-media-through-a-funnel/.  Though it takes advantage of many simplifying assumptions, it approaches being a "theory of funnels".  But if you compare powdered sugar to sand, you may need to consider how humidity affects the tendency of powdered sugar to clump together.  Tapping the funnel may break apart the powdered sugar clumps, whereas the sand may have smoothly rounded hard surfaces.